# tab_model() from sjplot produces "Error: 'is_empty_object' is not an exported object from 'namespace:insight'"

Tags: r, package, install.packages, sjplot

Even when I use the example dataset from the sjplot package I get the error "Error: 'is_empty_object' is not an exported object from 'namespace:insight'". Any ideas of what could be causing it?

For example, this error comes up when I run the following code:

```
data(mtcars)
m.mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
tab_model(m.mtcars)
```

Thank you!

Benji

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried with error?

Comment: Sure @Quinten, I just edited my original question with an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the "effectsize" package!